# How do I edit a validation expression to allow apostrophes

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

Currently I have this to allow only text and apostrophes

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regSearchTM" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[aA-zZ],[']" />
```

But it does not work

Comment: "But it does not work."  So what happens?

Comment: "But it does not work."... Can you expand on that? Are you getting errors (and if so what are they)? Are you getting a result set that is not filtered properly?

Answer (score 3):

Just include it as part of your character range check, you don't need to treat it as a separate check i.e.

```
[aA-zZ']
```